# Сделал телеграм бота на telegraf с использованием npm CronJob, но планировщик выполняется один раз после запуска

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, cron

Сделал все по документации, после запуска бота, выполняется один раз в 21:00, на следующий день уже нет,  нужно чтобы каждый день приходило, ниже будет код, что я сделал не так?
бот лежит на heroku

```
bot.start((msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.message.chat.id;
  msg.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, 'Bshop', buttonsStart);
});

bot.action('subscribe', async (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.update.callback_query.message.chat.id;
  await msg.answerCbQuery();
  await msg.reply(
    'Введите свой номер, который записан на сайте BSHOP (если при регистрации вы указывали номер в формате +77777779999, сюда пишите в таком же формате)',
  );

  //Каждый день в 21:00,получение кассы и статистики за день
  var getStatistik = new CronJob(
    '0 21 * * *',
    function () {
      getKassaStaticstick(msg, chatId, buttonsAny);
    },
    null,
    true,
    'Asia/Almaty',
  );
  getStatistik.start();

  //Каждый день в 9:00, ПОЗДРАВЛЕНИЕ С ДНЕМ РОЖДЕНИЯ
  var bDay = new CronJob(
    '0 9 * * *',
    function () {
      const now = moment().tz('Asia/Almaty').format();
      let year = now.slice(0, 4),
        month = now.slice(5, 7),
        day = now.slice(8, 10),
        nowDay = `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
      axios.get('*****************').then(function async(res) {
        res.data.map(async (item) => {
          if (item.chatID == chatId && item.birthday.substr(0, 5) == nowDay.slice(0, 5)) {
            await msg.telegram.sendMessage(
              chatId,
              `С днем рождения! Желаем Вам успеха и процветания`,
            );
          }
        });
      });
    },
    null,
    true,
    'Asia/Almaty',
  );
  bDay.start();

  //Раз в месяц  , напоминание об оплате
  var payDay = new CronJob(
    '0 9 1 * *',
    function () {
      const now = moment().tz('Asia/Almaty').format();

      let year = now.slice(0, 4),
        month = now.slice(5, 7),
        day = now.slice(8, 10),
        nowDay = `${day}.${month}.${year}`;
      msg.telegram.sendMessage(chatId, `Напоминание об оплате вашего счета BSHOP, ${nowDay}`);
    },
    null,
    true,
    'Asia/Almaty',
  );
  payDay.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Правильно, что у вас кронтаск запускается всего один раз в 21:00, так, как это указано в расписании. Ошибка в том, что не указано значение шага, через которое действие будет повторяться.

`0 21 * * *` - означает выполнение в 21:00

`0 21 */1 * *` - означает **выполнение в 21:00 каждый день месяца**, где */1 - и есть шаг, равный 1 дню

Чтоб протестировать выражение расписания(shedule expression), есть множество полезных ресурсов, которые вроде даже указаны в документации к npm пакету `cron`. Например:

- [Crontab.guru](https://crontab.guru/#0_21_*/1_*_*)
- [cronjob.xyz](https://cronjob.xyz/)

Для полного понимания полезно будет почитать мануал по cron: [http://crontab.org/](https://crontab.org/)